# Mule ESB Facebook Connector: store and restore accesstoken

Tags: mule-studio, facebook-access-token, mule-flow

I'm working with the Mule ESB 3.4 and the IDE MuleStudio 3.4.0 on a flow to login to facebook, using the facebook-cloud-connector. The auth works fine, but now I'm looking for a way to re/store the generated accesstoken I recieve from facebook via:

```
<facebook:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="7081" remotePort="7081" />
```

I currently use the following snippet to persist the auth-data to disk:

```
<facebook:oauth-store-config objectStore-ref="_defaultUserObjectStore">
```

The question is: How can I store the information, an objectstore, into a database?

Cheers!

**EDIT**: For everyone who wants struggled on the same point. I've create a Class which inherits the ObjectStore class from the mule api. After that, I've overriden the Store method, which gets called, when an accesstoken is requested by the mule-facebook-connector.

Comment: Is this the only way to store such kind of object (oAuth tokens) in Mule? I'm trying the Google Connector and I need to store it's oAuth token too. I'll try your approach here.

Thanks.